# kotlin-native freeze() method crashing when freezing a function

Tags: ios, kotlin, worker, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I am trying to freeze a function to be able to pass to a worker. In the same class as the function I have a variable which is marked with `ensureNeverFrozen`. This variable is not used in the function I am trying to freeze, in fact, the function does not do anything.

Still, when I try to freeze the function, I get the below error

Minimal crash reproducing [code](https://github.com/kerry/CoreKN/tree/freezing_crash) -

```
Instances of kotlin.Error, kotlin.RuntimeException and subclasses aren't propagated from Kotlin to Objective-C/Swift.
Other exceptions can be propagated as NSError if method has or inherits @Throws annotation.
Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.native.concurrent.FreezingException: freezing of function performWork (Kotlin reflection is not available) has failed, first blocker is []
        at 0   lib                                 0x0000000102502a45 kfun:kotlin.Exception.<init>(kotlin.String?)kotlin.Exception + 85
        at 1   lib                                 0x0000000102502125 kfun:kotlin.RuntimeException.<init>(kotlin.String?)kotlin.RuntimeException + 85
        at 2   lib                                 0x00000001025265c1 kfun:kotlin.native.concurrent.FreezingException.<init>(kotlin.Any;kotlin.Any)kotlin.native.concurrent.FreezingException + 641
        at 3   lib                                 0x0000000102526a2e ThrowFreezingException + 222
        at 4   lib                                 0x0000000102575833 FreezeSubgraph + 2611
        at 5   lib                                 0x000000010258bcfb Kotlin_Worker_freezeInternal + 27
        at 6   lib                                 0x000000010252673b kfun:kotlin.native.concurrent.freeze@#GENERIC.()Generic + 59
        at 7   lib                                 0x000000010253e310 kfun:com.prateekgrover.lib.KNDispatchQueue.performWorkAsync() + 208
        at 8   lib                                 0x000000010253de1a kfun:com.prateekgrover.lib.Greeting.start() + 186
        at 9   lib                                 0x000000010254168d blockCopyHelper + 573
        at 10  ios_kn_sample                       0x000000010215471d $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 45 (/Users/prateek.grover/Documents/code/KotlinNative/KotlinNativeSample/core_lib_dup/ios_kn_sample/<compiler-generated>:<unknown>)
        at 11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104156d7f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
        at 12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104157db5 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        at 13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010415a7b9 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 1022
        at 14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104168632 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 351
        at 15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104168fca _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 130
        at 16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001045406b3 _pthread_wqthread + 583
        at 17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001045403fd start_wqthread + 13
```

Any explanation for the above behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're referring to this

```
actual class KNDispatchQueue {
    @ThreadLocal
    actual companion object Singleton {
        actual val sharedInstance: KNDispatchQueue = KNDispatchQueue()
    }

    private var workQueue: MutableList<KNWork> = mutableListOf()

    init {
        workQueue.ensureNeverFrozen()
    }

    actual fun performWorkAsync() {
        ::performWork.freeze()
    }

    fun performWork() {

    }
}
```

The function is part of the class. Assuming it tries to freeze that instance of itself, it's also freezing the rest of the graph. I commented out `ensureNeverFrozen` and it freezes.

Your syntax `::performWork` is pointing at the instance ref.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-function-and-property-references-since-11

Comment: so basically since the ::performWork is bound to its object (instance of KNDispatchQueue), it tries to free the whole instance?

Comment: Yes. Freeze grabs anything connected to the instance and freezes it. The error message is not great, though. They're usually a bit more clear.